# Excel's Pivot Table's Calculated Field with Date operations always return 0

Tags: excel, pivot-table, datediff, calculated-field

I have a Pilot Table which summarizes a lot of operations.

Each operation is dated:

```
Data       | Operation | Result
-----------|-----------|-------
01/09/2020 | A         | 3
05/10/2020 | B         | 4
07/11/2020 | C         | 5
13/11/2020 | B         | 3
20/11/2020 | B         | 8
01/12/2020 | C         | 3
01/12/2020 | A         | 9
```

So I have a column with a start date [ MIN( Date ) ] and final date [ Max( Date ) ]:

```
Operation | Start Date | End Date 
----------|------------|------------
 A        | 01/09/2020 | 01/12/2020
 B        | 05/10/2020 | 20/11/2020
 C        | 07/11/2020 | 01/12/2020
```

Now I need a column that returns the period (days) from start date to end date.

Using `=DATEDIF( MIN(DATE), MAX(DATE), "D" )` in the Calculated Field Formula does not work.  I would guess that's because the Max and Min dates are not in the same line.

I cannot use the start date and end date either as they calculated in the "Sum Values" field box.

I am probably missing some important concept here.
Thanks

Comment: Can't help with your specific problem, since you provide insufficient information to reproduce it, but you can simplify your formula. You don't need `DATEDIF` to calculate days duration. Dates are stored as serial numbers, so the days difference would be simply `EndDate - StartDate`. Might help to edit your question after taking a look at the HELP topics for [How do I Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and also [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @RonRosenfeld, it still not possible (added sample data) as the "calculated field" do not let me reference field "start date" and "end date", just the "date".

Comment: what do you mean @AnilGoyal?

Comment: Are you free to use powerpivot/powerquery in excel?

Comment: @AnilGoyal, yes.  The data to to the pivot table comes from a Power Query created from  Table.Combine other tables (PQ).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can accomplish this easily in `Power Query` (`Get & Transform`) available in Excel 2010+

With you cursor in the table, navigate to:

- `Data`=> `Get & Transform` => `from Table/Range`
- The Power Query UI will open, with the data table loaded.
- Change the Type of the date column from `datetime` to `date`
- Then select the `Operation` column and

  - Group by

    - Advanced
    - Add aggregations of Min and Max for the start and end dates

[image]

- Add a custom column with the formula `=Duration.Days([End Date]-[Start Date])`

[image]

- Close and load

**MCode**

```
et
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table3"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Date", type date}, {" Operation ", type text}, {" Result", Int64.Type}}),
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Changed Type", {" Operation "}, {{"Start Date", each List.Min([Date]), type nullable date}, {"End Date", each List.Max([Date]), type nullable date}}),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "Duration", each Duration.Days([End Date]-[Start Date]))
in
    #"Added Custom"
```

[image]

Comment: I was about to post solution on similar lines.  Upvoted.

Comment: Wow! Table.Group() is what I have being looking for.
It acts like a SELECT DISTINCT and I can now forget about Pivot Tables!
Thanks!

Comment: @rsd And I just read your comment about the table coming from PQ, so you could probably incorporate this code into that query.